# dplyr: change variable according to grouping specifics

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to update a entry depending on which other entries are present in in the same group.

With reference to the toy example: I would like to change "C" (camp) into "B" (camp_1), in case the variable both.camp == 0 and in case the group is missing precisely a "C".

Toy dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,0,0,0),date=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),both.camps=c(0,0,0,1,1,1),camp=c("A","A","C","A","B","C"))


  ID date both.camps camp
1  1    1          0    A
2  1    1          0    A
3  1    1          0    C
4  0    1          1    A
5  0    1          1    B
6  0    1          1    C
```

Attempted code:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(ID,date) %>% mutate(camp_2=ifelse(both.camps==0 & camp=="C" & !"B" %in% camp ,"B",
                                                              ifelse(both.camps==0 & camp=="C" & !"A" %in% camp, "A", camp)))
```

Ideal result

```
desiderata <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,0,0,0),date=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),both.camps=c(0,0,0,1,1,1),camp=c("A","A","C","A","B","C"), camp_2=c("A","A","B","A","B","C"))

  ID date both.camps camp camp_2
1  1    1          0    A      A
2  1    1          0    A      A
3  1    1          0    C      B
4  0    1          1    A      A
5  0    1          1    B      B
6  0    1          1    C      C
```

Comment: I think you need to check the `camp` in input and output.  It changed from A B C to A B B

Comment: your camp column is different between the data and the result examples

Comment: I changed it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick on the small dataset, I am not sure it is the best method still.

```
data <- data %>% 
         group_by(ID,date) %>% 
         mutate(camp_2=ifelse(camp=="C" & all(both.camps==0) & !any("B" %in% camp) ,"B",
                                                                  ifelse(camp=="C" & all(both.camps==0) & !any("A" %in% camp),"A", as.character(camp))))
```